# how to make two dimensional array to a single array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to convert this two dimensional array to a single array ,
my array structure is something like below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => AccountTransaction Object
                (

                    [atrtid:AccountTransaction:private] => 1

                )

            [1] => AccountTransaction Object
                (

                    [atrtid:AccountTransaction:private] => 2

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => AccountTransaction Object
                (

                    [atrtid:AccountTransaction:private] => 1

                )

            [1] => AccountTransaction Object
                (

                    [atrtid:AccountTransaction:private] => 2

                )

        )

)
```

I want it to be

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => AccountTransaction Object
            (

                [atrtid:AccountTransaction:private] => 1

            )

        [1] => AccountTransaction Object
            (

                [atrtid:AccountTransaction:private] => 2

            )


        [2] => AccountTransaction Object
            (

                [atrtid:AccountTransaction:private] => 1

            )

        [3] => AccountTransaction Object
            (

                [atrtid:AccountTransaction:private] => 2

            )



    )
```

How can I convert it to below format .so that everything will come in a single array instead of multi dimensional array.
Is there any proper way to do it ?.so that it will be easier for me for the further processing..

Is there any suggestion ?

Comment: `call_user_func_array('array_merge', $yourArray)`

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also provide a [mcve].

Comment: "How can I convert it to below format" – You do it by writing a program which does that. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* narrow your problem down to a concise, focused, simple, short, reproducible [mcve] and ask a focused, narrow question on [so].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do in a below way:

```
$singleArray = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $twoDimensionalArray);
```